# One constant value for multiple classes

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, global

Let's say that I have six different classes and three of them should use the same constant value. What can we do? We either:

- Define as global variable

  ```
  A = 1

  class B:
      def __init__(self):
          self.a = A

  class C:
      def __init__(self):
          self.a = A

  class D:
      def __init__(self):
          self.a = A
  ```
- Define as class level for 1 class and give it to another class:

  ```
  class B:
      A = 1
      def __init__(self):
          self.b = 2

  class C:
      def __init__(self, a):
          self.a = a
          self.b = 3

  b = B()
  c = B(a=b.A)
  ```

The second way I just made up and as for me it's dirty and not convenient. Is there any way to avoid using a global variable?

Comment: If they should all have access to the same value, couldn't they inherit from something that has it as an attribute? Also *"constant variable"* is kind of an oxymoron.

Comment: Do you *really* need a variable inside the classes? If so, why?

Comment: That looks exactly like the case for globals.

Comment: Frankly, your problem is too abstract to have an answer. Please explain your *real* need, the problem you actually found. Show the real class names, how these classes are used. If there is no real need, then there is no real answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use class inheritance:

```
class Holder:
    a = 4


class A(Holder):
    pass

print A().a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use inheritance, using `B` as the base class

```
class B:
    A = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        B.__init__(self)
        self.a = B.A
        self.b = 3

b = B()
c = C()
print c.a
```

Comment: Just because `B` and `C` both have the same value, that does not mean one should inherit from the other.